# Amazon S3 - different lifecycle rule for "subdirectory" than for parent "directory"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have the following data structure:

- /
- /foo
- /foo/bar
- /foo/baz

Is it possible to assign to it the following life-cycle rules:

- / (1 month)
- /foo (2 months)
- /foo/bar (3 months)
- /foo/baz (6 months)

The official documentation is unfortunately self-contradictionary in this regard. It doesn't seem to work with AWS console, which makes me somewhat doubtful that SDKs/REST would be any different ;)

Failing at that my root problem is: I have 4 types of projects. The most rudimentary type has a few thousand projects, the other ones have a few dozen. Each type I am obligated to store for a different period of time. Each project contains hundreds of thousands of objects. It looks more or less as:

- type A, 90% of projects, x storage required
- type B, 6% of projects, 2x storage required
- type C, 3% of projects, 4x storage required
- type D, 1% of projects, 8x storage required

So far so simple. However. Projects may be upgraded or downgraded from one type to another. And as I said - I have a few thousand instances of the first type so I can't write specific rules for every one of them (remember 1000 rule limit per bucket). And since they may upgrade from one type to another I can't simply insert them in a their own folders as well (ex. only projects from a particular type) or bucket. Or so I think? Are there any other options open to me other than iterating over every object, every time I want to purge expired files - which I would seriously rather not do because of the sheer number of objects?

Maybe some kind of file "move/transfer" between buckets that doesn't modify the creation time metadata, and isn't costly for our server to process?

Would be much obliged :)

Answer (score 30):

Lifecycle policies are based on **prefix**, not "subdirectory."

So if objects matching the `foo/` prefix are to be deleted in 2 months, it is not logical to ask for objects with a prefix of `foo/bar/` to be deleted in 3 months, because they're going to be deleted after 2 months... since they also match the prefix `foo/`.  Prefix means prefix.  Delimiters are not a factor in lifecycle rules.

Also note that keys and prefixes in S3 do not begin with `/`.  A policy affecting the entire bucket uses the empty string as a prefix, not `/`.

You do, also, probably want to remember the trailing slashes when you specify prefixes, because `foo/bar` matches the file `foo/bart.jpg` while `foo/bar/` does not.

Iterating over objects for deletion is not as bad as you make it out to be, since the List Objects API call returns 1000 objects per request (or fewer, if you want), and allows you to specify both prefix and delimiter (usually, you'll use `/` as the delimiter if you want the responses grouped using the pseudo-folder model the console uses to create the hierarchical display)... and each object's key and datestamp is provided in the response XML.  There's also an API request to delete multiple objects in one call.

Any kind of move, transfer, copy, etc. will always reset the creation date of the object.  Even modifying the metadata, because objects are immutable.  Any time you move, transfer, copy, or "rename" an object (which is actually copy and delete), or modify metadata (which is actually copy to the same key, with different metadata) you are actually creating a new object.

Comment: I'm well aware that there is no concept of a "directory" in S3. That's precisely why I wrote "directory".

I also see no conceptual or theoretical problem with "overlapping prefixes" - where an object is assigned simply the life cycle rule that matches it's key most fully. In fact the documentation clearly states (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) that exactly this is possible.

As for your proposed solution - I understand that it is not possible in any way to "query" objects to be listed before we retrieve them? In this particular case - by date.

Comment: Assuming "querying" by metadata is not possible. It would be my natural instinct that iterating over (tens- hundreds- of) thousands of objects for thousands of projects, checking metadata for each single one, and then based on that building a list of objects to remove for each project isn't the best idea in the world.

However admittedly I have no prior experience with key-value stores. Am I simply being paranoid, and brute force is a way to go?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to in the docs regarding "the lifecycle rule that matches its key most fully."  I will investigate further but I don't believe there is any kind of "best match" logic.  Querying by metadata is indeed not possible, though for some buckets, I use S3 event notifications to maintain a synchronized index of objects, with their metadata indexed in a MySQL database.  DynamoDB or SimpleDB would also suit this purpose.  Brute force is not ideal but for periodic bucket auditing or cleanup it's viable.

Comment: I specifically mean paragraph - Example 6: Specify Multiple Rules with Overlapping Prefixes.

Given all of the above, if there isn't anything left that I'm too blindsghted to see. A synchronised index on our DB with assigned object metadata - seems like the most optimal solution so far.

Comment: Ah, okay, [that's a different page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#lifecycle-configuration-examples) at least on the mobile version of the docs.  These overlapping rules don't conflict, because they don't ask for incompatible things; I *think* it is the intention of the surrounding text to say that both rules would apply to the inner prefix (change to Standard/IA after 1 month, delete after 12).  Your rules in the question conflict with each other.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same issue and bypassed it using tags.
This solution would be in two steps:

1. Use a lambda function to tag object, and link the tag value to the object's prefix
2. Use the "tag" parameters of your lifecycle rule

#### Example of lambda function

In your use case, you want for example a 6-month expiration time for the objects with the `/foo/baz` prefix.
You can write a lambda like similar to this:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import re

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    #Get the object from the event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    
    tags = {
        "delete_after_six_months": "true" if re.match(pattern=".*\/foo\/baz\/.*", string=key) else "false"
    }
    
    # applies tags
    try:
        response = s3.put_object_tagging(
            Bucket = bucket,
            Key = key,
            Tagging={
                'TagSet': [{'Key': k, 'Value': v} for k, v in tags.items()]
            }
        )
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error applying tags to {}'.format(key))
        raise e
```

The trigger is to be adapted to the user's needs.
Using this, all objects with `/foo/baz/` prefix will have a `delete_after_six_months: true` tag, and you can easily define the proper associated expiration policy.

Answer (score 0):

@Zardii you can use unique s3 object tags [1] for the objects under these prefixes

Then you can apply the life cycle policy by tag with varying retention/deletion period.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html

### **Prefix**              -     **S3 Tags**

**/**                      *tag=>*   delete_after_one_month

**/foo**                 *tag=>* delete_after_two_months

**/foo/bar**             *tag=>* delete_after_three_months

**/foo/baz**             *tag=>* delete_after_six_month

Comment: I don't believe this will work as you are implying.  Even if you create a "directory" object in S3 and tagged it, objects below that prefix will not inherit the tag.