# AWS S3 Lifecycle Expiration Prefix Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to delete the previous versions of files in an S3 bucket that are not in a folder but directly uploaded in a bucket and also with a specific prefix.
Eg. Some S3 keys are like:

1. signed_2020_04_15.pdf
2. signed_2020_04_17.pdf
3. unsigned_2020_04_15.pdf
4. unsigned_2020_04_17.pdf
5. info/signed_2020_04_16.pdf
6. info/unsigned_2020_04_16.pdf

So I want my lifecycle to delete only the previous versions of the files starting with `signed_` but **not** the ones in the folder `info`. That means in the above list only `signed_2020_04_15.pdf` and `signed_2020_04_17.pdf` must be deleted.

How do I put my prefix? I tried prefix as `signed_` and waited for the lifecycle policy to run but it doesn't work. But in another bucket, the prefix was like `folder/` and it works.

So, do lifecycle policies work only for the files that are in a folder and not the ones that are uploaded directly?

Comment: [Amazon S3 - different lifecycle rule for “subdirectory” than for parent “directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35543840/174777) suggests that a Prefix doesn't have to match a directory name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: It works after 48 hours with prefix `signed_`. Just that AWS takes a bit more time is all.

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding what a prefix is. Set it to `signed_` and then wait 48 hours for the rule to actually do anything. The prefix is the leftmost characters of the object key, which includes any "folder" components... so prefix `ca` matches `cat.png` and `cat/photo.png` but not `photos/cat.png`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you. It got deleted after waiting for 48hrs