# AWS S3 lifecycle with overlapping lifecycle rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I am planning to have below lifecycle rules in my s3 bucket.

```
folder1/*      -> Move to Glacier in 100 days
folder1/USA/*  -> Move to the glacier in 500 days
```

Is there any way for us to achieve this?
I tried creating a rule with prefix `folder1/USA/` & another rule that applies to `all the objects`. I guess the one with all the objects overrides the previous one.

Here `folder1` can contain N number of subfolders.

I know there is a kind of similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543185/amazon-s3-different-lifecycle-rule-for-subdirectory-than-for-parent-directo) which is 7 years old. Any help would be appreciated.