# applying two rules in S3 bucket lifecycle policy for subfolders using terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have s3 bucket "my-bucket" which contains multiple objects and folders. this bucket also contains the "TestDataQA" folder. I want policy which will delete object from "my-bucket" after 30 days.  Also I dont want to delete objects(or want to delete after 10000 days) from "TestDataQA" folder which is inside "my-bucket" bucket.

I have written the code for it in .tfe file as below :

```
resource "aws_s3control_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my-lifecycle-conf" {
  bucket = my-bucket
    
  rule {
    id = "thousands-days-data"
      expiration {
      days = 10000
    }
    filter {
      prefix = "TestDataQA/"
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
    
  rule {
    id = "30-days-data"
      expiration {
      days = 30
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

My question is will it work? the objects from bucket will be deleted after 30 days and from subfolders  "TestDataQA/" it will be deleted only after 10000 days. it will work this way or am I missing anything?

I have plan and apply the above tfe code and it run successfully. My only concern will it work or delete all objects including above mentioned subfolder after 30 days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 - different lifecycle rule for "subdirectory" than for parent "directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543185/amazon-s3-different-lifecycle-rule-for-subdirectory-than-for-parent-directo)

Comment: You can see policy examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html), for reference. You should probably review the bucket policies produced by Terraform and validate the behavior here before you rely on it for production data. Do a simple test with, for example, 1 day expiration and 5 day expiration.